# when trying call push_back of std::vector in gdb, got "Attempt to take address of value not located in memory"

Tags: stl, gdb

I would like to create and mock some STL data via gdb when a program is being debugged.

I used the following commands in **gdb** to gain access to a block of memory for std::vector, and then set its allocator, and finally called the "push_back" function to fill in with a int number. 
However, gdb just showed me the message of "**Attempt to take address of value not located in memory.**" when calling push_back.

Please note that I have already realized that the argument of "push_back" is a const reference. Therefore, I "**malloc**"ed a piece of memory on heap to store the argument.

This is the gdb call:

```
(gdb) set $vect =  ('std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>'*) malloc (sizeof('std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>')) 
(gdb) set $alloc = ('std::allocator<int>'*)malloc(sizeof('std::allocator<int>'))
(gdb) set (std::allocator<int>)($vect->_M_impl) = *$alloc
(gdb) set $vect->_M_impl._M_start = 0  
(gdb) set $vect->_M_impl._M_finish = 0
(gdb) set $vect->_M_impl._M_end_of_storage = 0
(gdb) p *$vect
$21 = {<std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >> = {
    _M_impl = {<std::allocator<int>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, _M_start = 0x0, _M_finish = 0x0, _M_end_of_storage = 0x0}}, <No data fields>}
(gdb) set $num = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int))
(gdb) set *$num = 5             
(gdb) p *$num
$22 = 5
(gdb) call $vect->push_back(*$num)
Attempt to take address of value not located in memory.
```

The gdb version is 7.6.1.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a bug in the gdb expression evaluator.  It is in the gdb bugzilla somewhere (I think originally reported with some test case using `std::string`).